# How can you find the rotation of a terrain based on a coordinate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, terrain

I wondered how i could find the rotation on a terrain point using a Vector3?

```
public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Terrain terrain;
    public Vector3 area;

    [HideInInspector]
    public List<Vector3> points;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public float minDistance;

    private void Start()
    {
        terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();

        #region PlaceVector3
        for (int x = 0; x < area.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < area.y; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < area.z; z++)
                {
                    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                    pos.y = terrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(x, y, z));
                    points.Add(pos);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Spawn(prefab);
    }

    private Vector3 GetMousePos()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            return hit.point;
        }
        else return Vector3.zero;
    }

    public void Spawn(GameObject obj)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 tempVec = Vector3.zero;
            foreach (Vector3 vec3 in points)
            {
                if (Vector3.Distance(vec3, GetMousePos()) < Vector3.Distance(tempVec, GetMousePos()))
                    tempVec = vec3;
            }
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(tempVec, Vector3.up, out hit, 1f))
            {
                print(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
            GameObject GO = Instantiate(obj, tempVec, Quaternion.identity);

            //TODO INSERT THE ROTATION OF THE TERRAIN ROTATION AT POINT TEMPVEC

        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see my code, here i simple draw a grid then get the height of the point by accessing the terrain data. My question is how i can get the rotation (normal) into a Quaternion value, when i know the point. I tried to get the rotation by using `Vector3.Angle(tempVec, Vector3.up)`, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: There isn't a unique orientation corresponding to a given normal. If you want to construct an arbitrary orientation that aligns one of the object's axes with the normal, there are ways to do that. As is though, the problem appears to be underspecified.

Comment: To add to @scg's comment.  The reason why there's no unique orientation is because you also need to figure out what the orientation -around- the normal should be.   This is why Quaternion.SetLookRotation takes two parameters.  You can use Quaternion.SetLookRotation by passing your normal into the first parameter, but you still need to figure out a vector that is orthogonal to the normal to pass in for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As the other comments have said, your question doesn't really make sense as written. A single direction mapping doesn't make a unique rotation, and the normal is just one direction.

What I would recomment is change your `Spawn` method to accept a specified *forward* direction, and then use that forward direction and the normal to make the rotation you're interested in using [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html):

```
private void Update()
{
    Spawn(prefab, Vector3.forward); // or whatever forward direction makes sense.
}

public void Spawn(GameObject obj, Vector3 objForward)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 tempVec = Vector3.zero;
        foreach (Vector3 vec3 in points)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(vec3, GetMousePos()) < Vector3.Distance(tempVec, GetMousePos()))
                tempVec = vec3;
        }
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(tempVec, Vector3.up, out hit, 1f))
        {
            print(hit.transform.gameObject);

            Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(objForward, hit.normal);
            GameObject GO = Instantiate(obj, tempVec, rot);
        }
    }
}
```